# English comparative words (than, so, as, and maybe like): why are they so weird?

Tags: etymology, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, semantics, comparisons

I promise this is an actual, answerable question. But I want to explain myself when I call these specific words "weird"; English is so often "exceptional" that referring to any particular part of it as being weird seems unnecessary. These comparative words have bothered me for a while.

*Than* is a bit of an odd word in English. Wiktionary (I don't have access to the OED) gives two definitions; one is a conjunction and the other a preposition. I want to focus on its use as a conjunction.

First of all, *than* is bizarrely "active" when compared to other frequently-used conjunctions. I'm afraid that I don't know the technical term for this, but I think it makes sense: *and* just connects two or more things, *but* disconnects (well, negatively connects I suppose) two or more things, *or* and *nor* express alternation, and *yet* is similar to *but* although I'd say *yet* is a bit more disconnecting. (*And* actually has an "active" form, seen in statements like "try that and you'll get shot!", wherein *and* is used to express some sort of causation. *Or* has a similar negative usage: "don't run quickly or you'll fall". But note that negating the second part forces *and*: "don't run quickly and you won't fall".) *If* is similar in this respect: it too has a function of "introducing" a kind of statement. In a language that doesn't have a lot of morphology, like English, these words are often *necessary* to form certain kinds of statements, whereas in more marked languages they may not be. In Latin, the "ablative of comparison" is a construction wherein the comparative form of an adjective is used to compare two nouns, one being in the nominative or accusative case, and one being in the ablative case, as in

> *Catō est **Cicerōne** ēloquentior*
>   'Cato is more eloquent than Cicero'

(very literally, 'Cato is, than Cicero, more eloquent'); in this usage the use of the ablative for expressing "movement away from" is extended to stating that two things are different as though they were moving apart ([source](https://archive.org/details/allengreenoughsn00alleiala/page/254)). Of course, Latin *quam* is also used for comparisons, having a very similar function to English *than*; we'll see more about *quam* later.

So *than* has a lot to say. I place it in the same class as (some uses of) *as*, *so*, and even *like* (though *than* is a bit of an outlier). These all can be used to compare two or more things; the difference is that *than* (although one use of *as* fits too; see below) can *contrast* (what I'll call disjunctive comparison) while *as*, *so*, and *like* are used more to connect two or more things. But the fact that they're used to compare is not the only reason that these conjunctions/prepositions/adverbs are unique. They seem to be special in that they accept much more ellipsis than other conjunctions. Take for instance (1):

> (1) She does that much better than I do.

We'll speak of a "left side" and a "right side" of such statements as (1): in this case, the right side "I do" is technically an abbreviation of the predicate of the left side "She does that". (There's a third part of the sentence, which we'll call the "comparative part"; in this case, it's "much better".) Therefore the right side, when "expanded", is *I do that*. In practice, the right side is actually frequently more abbreviated than it already is:

> (2) She does that better than I/me.

The choice of the nominative (*I*) or oblique (*me*) forms to use in statements like (2) is traditionally informed by what exactly the right side is saying. Here, since the right side is contrasting something with the *subject* of the left side, it is regarded as more correct to have the right side be in the same nominative form. But then there's (3), where the right side is not really abbreviating anything:

> (3) He ran faster than ten miles per hour.

The right side of (3) can hardly be understood as ellipsis for "ten miles per hour ran". This is the prepositional use of *than*. Accordingly, pronouns should be in their oblique form when used as such; but here we have a problem. If we're comparing two pronouns with *than*, it could often go either way:

> (4) **A** ran faster than **B**.

If we're comparing the *speed* as an attribute of **A**'s running with that of **B**, then **A**, as the subject of the sentence, should be in the nominative form, and **B**, the object of the preposition *than* "should" be in the oblique form as in (4.1).

> (4.1) I ran faster than him.

However, we could also be comparing the *manner* of **A**'s running with that of **B**; in this case (4.2) is "more correct".

> (4.2) I ran faster than he [did/did run].

This is far too fine of a distinction to make most of the time; I can't think of any examples where it would actually matter. The "erroneous" use of the *conjunction* *than* with oblique pronouns seems to have stemmed from reinterpretation of *than*, being commonly placed directly between the two things one is comparing and also different from the other conjunctions, as always being a preposition and thus putting the nouns in their oblique forms (as is done with prepositions).

Now we need to turn to *as*, *so*, and *like*. By all accounts these are usually prepositions, although often extended into conjunctions. This is true of several words, and indeed many conjunctions in many languages started out as prepositions. *As* has many meanings. Wiktionary gives *as* a definition as an adverb, conjunction, and preposition. They all have a similar underlying meaning of "while" or "at the same time"; I believe that it is from this that the comparative meaning is extended. In (5) we have an modification of (4) with the *as*...*as* coordinate pair instead of *than*:

> (5) **A** ran *as* fast *as* **B**.

Even though the meaning has changed from a disjunctive comparison to one that equates the left and right sides, the problem of determining the function of **B** is the same as in (4). **B** might stand for the subject of *run*, and "should" therefore be in the nominative; it could also be the object of a preposition. In this case, the issue is further compounded by the fact that *as* appears twice. It seems that the first and second *as* are really different words -- or at least different senses of the same word. *As* is also a synonym of *so*, and *so* has a comparative sense on its own; (6) is the title of a movie, but it illustrates this well:

> (6) As above, so below.

In (6), *as* and *so* also coordinate: "[just] as [it is] above, [it is] so below". Obviously this is quite a poetic turn of phrase, but it is valid; in older writing the *as*...*so* construction is quite frequently encountered, in forms like that of (7.1):

> (7.1) As **X** is **Y**, so also **Z**.

(7.1)'s right side ("also **Z**") shows ellipsis of *is* in the left side; the "full" form would be as in (7.2).

> (7.1) As **X** is **Y**, so also is **Z**.

*So* can also stand on its own, while still retaining the meaning; however, it becomes part of an independent clause as a result (because it no longer has support from *as*):

> (7.3) **X** is **Y**; so also **Z**.

The function of *as* in (7) at first seems to be expressing *cause*, and replacing it with *because* should produce a statement that is as valid, but it doesn't really.

> (7.4) *Because **X** is **Y**, so also **Z**

I wouldn't be surprised to find this, necessarily, but it sounds odd to me. This emphasizes the way in which this group of words is different from the other conjunctions: *because* tolerates ellipsis to a much lesser degree than they (haha). Because of this, the whole issue of case doesn't apply.

*Like* is similar, but less versatile. Its ellipsis-accepting comparative usage seems to be less, and more recent ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/like#Usage_notes_3) has an interesting (though unsourced) bit of information about this) than that of the others. It can often replace *as* when it isn't paired with another *as*:

> (8.1) He runs as I do.
>   (8.2) He runs like I do.

There is a slight difference in meaning though: (8.1) seems to be more "absolute", comparing his running's existence to that of my running, while (8.2) compares his manner of running with mine; however, in context, they could both have the same meaning:

> (8.3) When we race, he runs as I do.
>   (8.4) When we race, he runs like I do.

Note that *as*, *so*, and *like*, while ellipsis-tolerant, are less so than *than*. (9.1) is correct, but (9.2), (9.3), and (9.4) are less valid ((9.2) sounds the most correct to my ears).

> (9.1) He runs faster than I.
>   (9.2) *He runs as fast as I.
>   (9.3) *He runs like I.
>   (9.4) *As he runs, so I.

---

In other languages, the behavior of comparative words is similar. Latin *quam* was mentioned above, but Latin's ways of comparing two things are extensive. *Quam* corresponds closely to English *than*. Latin, being heavily inflected, requires the left and right side to be in the *same* case, regardless of which out of the five/six/seven they be. This is similar to English, although English only marks pronouns for case, so it's hard to determine whether a word is a subject or an object out of context. Latin also has *tam*, which, when coupled with *quam*, provides an *as*...*so* or *as*...*as*-like meaning.

Spanish has *que* 'than' and *tan*...*como* 'as...as/as...so' for comparisons: *eres más bello que yo* 'you are more beautiful than I' and *no conduzco tan rápido como tú* 'I do not drive as fast as thou dost' (just to keep things unambiguous). From examples I could find, it seems that you will most often find the right side in the nominative form. Further examples ([from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/como#Spanish)) illustrate this (translations slightly altered): *no es tan alta como nosotras* 'she is not as tall as we', *¿tienes tanta hambre como yo?* 'art thou as hungry as I?'. It would be incorrect to say **no es tan alta como nos* or **¿tienes tanta hambre como me?* (and I'm sure would sound pretty weird to a native speaker). Spanish also adheres to the "copulae requires nominative case" rule: *¿quién soy yo?* 'who am I' and not **¿quién soy me?* '*who am me'. Latin, of course, does this too.

I don't know enough about other languages, but I'd imagine the other Romance languages behave similarly.

---

I promised that this is a real question. Specifically, **I would like to know for what reason these words** (the group as a whole, a subset, or just an individual one) **behave like this**. What makes them so special? 
How did they come to mean what they do today (what is the history of these words)? I've written all I can say about their *current* use; I'm very interested in their history but I do not know of any sources for this ("conjunction development", I think, is sadly under-studied).

(*Than* and *so* have a similar origin as a form of an ancient pronoun; since this is also true of Latin's *quam* and *tam* I suspect that asking anything about this semantic development would be off-topic and more for a general linguistics site. *As* apparently derives from a contraction of *also*, which makes it an outlier here.)

Comment: "Than" is a preposition, not a conjunction.

Comment: @BillJ [*According to the view of many English-language prescriptionists, including influential 18th-century grammarian Robert Lowth, **than is exclusively a conjunction** and therefore takes either nominative (or subjective) or oblique (or objective) pronouns, depending on context, rather than exclusively oblique pronouns as prepositions do*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Than) Opinions differ...

Comment: @BillJ The general consensus seems to be that it can be used as either one, but they mean the same thing and are generally used the same way, so it doesn't really matter. The prescriptionists maintain there's a difference, though.

Comment: I just realized that @Mari-Lou A commented pretty much the exact same thing. Sorry.

Comment: @texdr.aft no problem whatsoever, you were composing while I posted my comment,  the more the merrier.

Comment: @BillJ I see. So it's "unique from the other conjunctions" simply because... it's not a conjunction. That makes a lot of sense. I still think that "than" is an interesting word. Where could one read more about this subject? I suppose it's just "syntax" in general?

Comment: @texdr.aft My comment contained a typo, so I reposted it. The claim that many so-called conjunctions (and adverbs) are actually prepositions was postulated by the great grammarian Oscar Jesperson (1924), so it has a sound pedigree. May I suggest that you look at some of the articles on the 'Net by the notable linguist Geoff Pullum, where he discusses the reclassification of many subordinating conjunctions as prepositions.

Comment: There are differences: subordinators function as markers of subordination, whereas preps like “than” function as heads of the constituents they introduce. And unlike subordinating conjunctions, preps have independent meaning ('an evident semantic content'). In the case of “than”, the meaning is a comparative one.

Comment: _Than_ occurs exclusively with comparative constructions, always introducing the baseline comparison constituent(s). I don't think that means it has a comparative meaning, or any more lexical meaning than _the_ or _of_.

Comment: Once again, your statements are true according to your definitions. Which are categorically stated, though they're not everyone's definitions. _Than_ is associated with comparatives, if that's what "has a comparative meaning" implies. Meaning is not, however, a syntactic criterion. You make a subtle distinction between _than_ as a preposition because it's a "head of a constituent", and other, headless, meaningless subordinators.